# OnKeyDown event not fired when pressing VK_LEFT on TComboBox or TButton

Tags: delphi

Is there a way to get the OnKeyDown event fired, when the VK_LEFT key is pressed on the TCheckBox or TButton control. Currently, it just selects another control, but doesn't fire that event.

**UPDATE**

Here is my code to use the key VK_LEFT like a TAB Back.

First, I needed to disable the standard behaviour of VK_LEFT on some controls like (TCheckBox, TButton, ...):

```
procedure TfmBase.CMDialogKey(var Message: TCMDialogKey);
begin
  if Message.CharCode <> VK_LEFT then
    inherited;
end;
```

then, the OnKeyDown event is also fired for VK_LEFT on TCheckBox, TButton, ... On that event I placed the code to select the previous control. KeyPreview must be true of course.

```
procedure TfmBase.FormKeyDown(Sender: TObject; var Key: Word;
  Shift: TShiftState);
var
  handled: Boolean;
begin
  if Key = VK_LEFT then
  begin
    handled := false;
    TabBack(handled); //This is my function, which checks the type of the control and selects the previous control.
    if handled then
      Key := 0;
  end;
end;
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You won't get that event to fire because that key press is interpreted as form navigation. The top level message loop recognises that this is a navigation key and diverts the message to perform that navigation.

If you want to handle this event then your only opportunity to do so is in `Application.OnMessage` which fires before the message is diverted.

**UPDATE**

In a comment you indicate that you want to intercept this event in order to perform navigation. Since the event is not firing because default navigation is being performed, perhaps the ideal solution is to override the default navigation.

I believe that the key routine that drives this is `TWinControl.CNKeyDown`. Reading through this code, I think you just need to handle `CM_DIALOGKEY` in your form and persuade the navigation to behave the way you want it to.

Your code should look something like this:

```
procedure TMyForm.CMDialogKey(var Message: TCMDialogKey);
begin
  if GetKeyState(VK_MENU) >= 0 then begin
    case Message.CharCode of
    VK_LEFT:
      if ActiveControl=MyControl1 then begin
        MyControl2.SetFocus;
        Message.Result := 1;
        Exit;
      end;
    end;
  end;
  inherited;
end;
```

Comment: Thank. Actually, I also want to use that key for form naviagation, but when such a control is placed in nested panels (e.g. TFlowPanel -> TPanel), then navigation is not working between TPanels. So I actually want to use it as a TAB (Back).

Comment: @max - In that case one other possibility is to handle `CM_CHILDKEY`, the message record has a 'Sender' member. If that sender is your particular checkbox, return non 0, set active control to the control that you desire, and don't call inherited.

Comment: @david: thanks, your suggestion worked. I added the procedure CMDialogKey(var Msg: TWMKey), and just set msg.Result := 0. Then the OnKeyDown event is fired.

Comment: @Sertac Handling `CM_CHILDKEY` as you suggest has the effect of bypassing `CM_DIALOGKEY`. However, you'd need to handle it in the control rather than the form. This is most certainly possible. However, since @max wants to do navigation I can't see a better solution that `CM_DIALOGKEY`. Don't you agree?

Comment: @max Ah, that's not quite what I mean. You'd only want to set `Msg.Result` to 0 if it matched both the key and control you were interested in. Otherwise you'll break all navigation on your form. What's more, `CMDialogKey` is designed for you to do the navigation right there and then. You just call `SetFocus` on the control that you want to navigate to. Do it this way and don't handle KeyDown at all!

Comment: @David - CM_CHILDKEY is performed on the form, that's why the message has a 'Sender' member. Dunno, as long as it works I don't see much difference. :)

Comment: @Sertac In the VCL source I'm looking at, I can only see it being performed on `TWinControl`.

Comment: @David - Yep, that's the form, not the checkbox. Would you try this in a CM_CHILDKEY handler of the form: `if (Message.CharCode = VK_LEFT) and (Message.Sender = CheckBox2) then begin` `Message.Result := 1;` `ActiveControl := Button1;` `end else inherited;`.

Comment: @Sertac OK, I see it now! `TWinControl.CMChildKey` converts it from a control message to a form message. Nice. I agree now that this is interchangeable with `CMDialogKey`.

Comment: Strange, as soon as I place that procedure (without any code), the standard naviagation (Arrow Keys) is disabled. It also doesn't matter which value msg.Result has. So checking for the right control doesn't make any change. Only when msg.Result <> 0, all standard behavior is disabled (like VK_ENTER, VK_TAB, ...).  I don't know what I have to return in order form navigation with the Arrow Keys will be enabled again?

Comment: @max You have to call inherited if you aren't handling it!

Comment: thx, just recognized it. Now it is working as expected. Thank you very much for your effort.

Comment: @david: your code is not invoked by all controls (e.g. TEdit, ...). So, I decided to just forward the VK_LEFT key in order I can handle it by the OnKeyDown event. So I can process every control I need. When the SelStart = 0 I also select the previous control. thx

Comment: @david Well, if a TEdit has the focus then you wouldn't want VK_LEFT to do form navigation surely. That would be interpreted as navigation within the edit. Anyway, you can work all that out for yourself I'm sure, but you clearly have the tools now. Either the way I suggested or Sertac's excellent alternative.

Comment: @David - *@david* ? You're keeping up with too many questions these days! ;)

Comment: @Sertac Er, yeah! Still, I'm done for today, all capped out! P.S. I liked your `CM_CHILDKEY` once I'd worked it out. I really learn a lot and polish up my knowledge doing these sorts of questions. I think I *get* the Delphi message pump more now than in the past after this Q.

Answer (score 4):

You need handling `WM_GETDLGCODE` message:

```
procedure WMGetDlgCode(var Message: TWMGetDlgCode); message WM_GETDLGCODE;
....
procedure TfmBase.WMGetDlgCode(var Message: TWMGetDlgCode);
 begin
   Message.Result:=DLGC_WANTALLKEYS or DLGC_WANTARROWS;
 end;
```

Comment: I had the same problem to intercept the KeyDown in TCheckBox, your tip worked 100% for me. Grateful.